# parts of cubic equation

Tags: cubics

Below there is a solved question from  a  book . [image]

I could not understand how they got $S_{n+3}$ = $S_{n+1}$ - $S_n$

Comment: I don't see $S_n + 1 = S_n + 1 - S_n$ written anywhere...

Comment: @DanielMcLaury in fourth line from last

Comment: I feel like something is missing...

Comment: The fourth line from the last says $S_{n+3} = S_{n+1} - S_n$.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury yeah , i mean that only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is a root of the equation, $\alpha^3 - \alpha + 1 = 0$ that is $\alpha^3 = \alpha - 1$. Now, $\alpha^{n+3} = \alpha^3 \alpha^n = (\alpha - 1)\alpha^n = \alpha^{n+1} - \alpha^n$. Summing over all three roots gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

All the exercise is centered onto [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities).
In particular, concerning your question, we have that putting
$$
x^3  - x + 1 = e_0 x^3  - e_1 x^2  + e_2 x - e_3  = 0
$$
then
$$
\begin{gathered}
  e_0  = 1 \hfill \\
  e_1  = 0 = S_1  \hfill \\
  e_2  =  - 1 = \frac{1}
{2}\left( {e_1 S_1  - S_2 } \right) =  - \frac{1}
{2}S_2  \hfill \\
  e_3  =  - 1 = \frac{1}
{3}\left( {e_2 S_1  - e_1 S_2  + S_3 } \right) = \frac{1}
{3}\left( { + 2 + S_3 } \right) \hfill \\
  e_4  = 0 = \frac{1}
{4}\left( {e_3 S_1  - e_2 S_2  + e_1 S_3  - S_4 } \right) = \frac{1}
{4}\left( {e_3 S_1  - e_2 S_2  + e_1 S_3  - S_4 } \right) \hfill \\
   \vdots  \hfill \\
  e_{n + 3}  = 0 = \frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 3} }}
{{n + 3}}\left( {e_3 S_n  - e_2 S_{n + 1}  + e_1 S_{n + 2}  - S_{n + 3} } \right) = \frac{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{n + 3} }}
{{n + 3}}\left( { - S_n  + S_{n + 1}  - S_{n + 3} } \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$